# Getting random and wrong values with C interface for a Struct with dynamic data and custom postcircumfix

Tags: raku, nativecall

i have a C file and a Raku file for connection. sometimes i get random and wrong values. files are as folows

C file: it has a struct called CField which Raku code will interact. Importantly it has a dynamically allocated attribute in it which is `data`. So i do 2 mallocs in `make_field` and 2 frees in `free_field`.

```c
// field.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct CField {
    void* data;
    size_t size;
};

void* checker_malloc(size_t n) {
    // malloc but checks if allocated fine
    void* p = malloc(n);
    if (!p) { fprintf(stderr, "can't allocate %zu bytes", n); exit(1); }
    return p;
}

struct CField* make_field(void* data, size_t data_size) {
    // malloc for all struct
    struct CField* new_field = checker_malloc(sizeof *new_field);

    // malloc for .data
    size_t num_bytes = data_size * sizeof(int32_t);
    new_field->data = checker_malloc(num_bytes);
    memcpy(new_field->data, data, num_bytes);

    new_field->size = data_size;
    
    return new_field;
}

void free_field(struct CField* v) {
    free(v->data);
    free(v);
}
```

Raku file: it has a Wrapper around this struct. I define `[]` operator here for Whatever passed i.e. `Wrapper.new(...)[*]` is to do somthing special. It essentially makes a new Wrapper out of current ones data.

```raku
## Field.rakumod
use NativeCall;

# C side
my constant LIB = "./libfield.so";
class CField is repr("CStruct") {...}

sub make_field(Pointer[void], size_t --> CField) is native(LIB) { * };
sub free_field(CField) is native(LIB) { * };

class CField {
    has Pointer $.data;
    has size_t  $.size;

    submethod DESTROY {
        free_field(self);
    }
}

# Raku side
class Wrapper is export {
    has CField $.field;
    has Int $.size;

    # New from Raku data
    multi method new(@data) {
        self.bless:
            field => make_field(nativecast(Pointer, CArray[int32].new(@data)), @data.elems),
            size => @data.elems;
    }

    # New from already Wrapper
    multi method new(Wrapper $other) {
        self.bless:
            field => make_field($other.field.data, $other.size),
            size => $other.size;
    }

    method as-list {
        # to see what is inside
        my $nat = nativecast(CArray[int32], $!field.data);
        $nat[^$!size].List
    }

    multi postcircumfix:<[ ]>(Wrapper:D $w, Whatever) is export {
        # new Wrapper object around $w, essentially copies it
        Wrapper.new($w)
    }
}
```

Now the reporduction to fail it:

```bash
$ tree
.
├── Field.rakumod
└── field.c

$ gcc -std=c99 -Wall -fPIC -shared -olibfield.so field.c

$ raku -I. -MField -e'for ^1_000 { my $a = Wrapper.new([1, 2, 3]); my $b = $a[*].as-list; die "$_: {$b.raku}" unless $b eqv (1, 2, 3) }; say "no error"'
no error

$ raku -I. -MField -e'for ^1_000 { my $a = Wrapper.new([1, 2, 3]); my $b = $a[*].as-list; die "$_: {$b.raku}" unless $b eqv (1, 2, 3) }; say "no error"'
446: $(38717712, 0, 3)
  in block <unit> at -e line 1
```

Sometimes it ends with "no error" as expected. But sometimes it dies as seen. Interestingly, if I comment `DESTROY` method in CField, its always "no error". But then memory leaks right? So what i am doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
$ raku -v  # Ubuntu 20.04
Welcome to Rakudo™ v2023.09.
Implementing the Raku® Programming Language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2023.09.
```

Comment: *"my $b = $a[\*].as-list;"* I think there is an issue with the temp object returned from postcircumfix, maybe it is freed to early? If I replace this with `my $c = $a[*]; my $b = $c.as-list` to save the temp object in a variable first, it seems to work fine

Comment: i get no error too in that case thanks. but that shouldnt happen right? still trying to get to method of that object so it shouldnt be destryoed yet?

Comment: in my ungolfed code i get error for even the bare "my $a = Wrapper.new(...); die unless $a.as-list eqv ...", where there is no temporary object. interesetingly, in the golfed version this doesnt error, i dont know what is going on really.

Comment: since you have variable behaviour, my guess is that the failure happens when the raku GC kicks in. (you may be able to vary the size of the item / or play with the time of the run to get a feel for large sizes / long times are more likely to fail whci would tend to confrom this hypothesis)

Comment: ^^ so in this case, maybe try always calling free just after create ... then maybe the error always happens ... then maybe step through the correctness of the destroy actions??

Comment: thanks but if i free right after making object i will access forbidden memory area and it will error always. in fact i did that and it dies on 0th iteration all the time as exptected. also i wrote some C code to test the C code if memory leaks, but valgrind reports no leaks possible so C code is doing its job fine. and as i wrote in question, if i comment the DESTROY method, no error. but then memory leaks